# Dynamically fill Row and Col inside Grid in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a react native app , i want to dynamically fill my grid layout with inputs from server , i want the result to be in that shape :

```
 <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.dark_orange, height: h(30) }}
          >
          </Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.green, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.gris, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.orange, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.purple, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col style={{ backgroundColor: colors.red, height: h(30) }}></Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.transparent, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.white, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.green, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.dark_orange, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.green, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.gris, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.transparent, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.white, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
          <Col
            style={{ backgroundColor: colors.green, height: h(30) }}
          ></Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

As you can see i hardcoded the inputs and the shape of the grid (each row has 3 columns), i want to make a function that take all the inputs from the server and render something like what i hardcoded .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'd need to get the shape of your data to reflect the grid:

```
// Outer array represents rows, inner array represents columns
const grid = [
  [
    { backgroundColor: colors.dark_orange, height: h(30) },
    ...
  ], [
    ...
  ]
]
```

Then, just use something like [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your data and return the relevant JSX:

```
const renderRow = (row) => {
  return <Row>{row.map(renderCol)}</Row>;
}

const renderCol = (col) => {
  const { backgroundColor, height } = col;
  return <Col style={{ backgroundColor, height }}></Col>;
};

<Grid>{grid.map(renderRow)}</Grid>
```